# Loopback access token does not work for postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopback

I build app using loopback 3.x and postgresql
I created an app by following tutorial.
By the way, I can't use access token gotten from login.
I get following exception:

> {"error":{"statusCode":500,"name":"AssertionError
>   [ERR_ASSERTION]","message":"token.created must be a valid
>   Date","generatedMessage":false,"code":"ERR_ASSERTION","actual":null,"expected":true,"operator":"==","stack":"AssertionError
>   [ERR_ASSERTION]: token.created must be a valid Date\n    at
>   ModelConstructor.AccessToken.validate
>   (F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback\common\models\access-token.js:229:7)\n
>   at
>   F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback\common\models\access-token.js:178:15\n
>   at
>   F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\dao.js:2176:5\n
>   at
>   F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\dao.js:2111:9\n
>   at
>   F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1012:9\n
>   at
>   F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:359:16\n
>   at iteratorCallback
>   (F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:935:13)\n
>   at
>   F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:843:16\n
>   at
>   F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1009:13\n
>   at buildResult
>   (F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\dao.js:2077:11)\n
>   at
>   F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\dao.js:2091:13\n
>   at doNotify
>   (F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:155:49)\n
>   at doNotify
>   (F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:155:49)\n
>   at doNotify
>   (F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:155:49)\n
>   at doNotify
>   (F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:155:49)\n
>   at Function.ObserverMixin._notifyBaseObservers
>   (F:\Angular2\stanapp\api\node_modules\loopback-datasource-juggler\lib\observer.js:178:5)"}}

I found [same article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27462545/loopback-accesstoken-not-persisted-to-database) posted 2 years ago, but there isn't answer.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: 'token.created must be a valid Date' is this Date value set before trying to access the token ?

Comment: I hooked loopback source yesterday. The created field of token is not saved with current time in postgresql. so the token validator asserts error when validating token